Short story about food called something like "Standard Fare"
I read this short story as a kid in one of those Fantasy and Horror Anthologies, but I can only vaguely remember the plot and I've been trying to find it for days. I think the main character is promoted and able to afford or otherwise receive food outside of the standardized rations called Standard Fare. I vaguely remember them living and working in a giant tower or something as I believe there was some sort of elevator that was important. I think at some point the protagonist and his wife are excited to try an egg.
I might have gotten some details scrambled with other stories, but I definitely remember Standard Fare. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

The Good Work by Theodore L. Thomas. It isn't a widely collected story. The only anthologies mentioned are 101 Science Fiction Stories from 1986 and and The Giant Book of Science Fiction Stories from 1992. Despite this it has already been asked about in Story about workers repeatedly doing trivial work and Name of science fiction short story needed. Includes factory, redundant work, although you are the first to ask specifically about the Standard Fare.
As you say the protagonist does live in a huge tower. The story starts with him going home after work:

Jeremiah Winthrop rode the spiral escalator up, up to the two-part cubicle he called home on the one hundred and forty-eighth floor. He stood swaying slightly as the escalator wound its serpentine way upwards. Others rode with him, tight people, tense people, pushed together, staring straight as they rode the spiral escalator up. And now and then at a turn or a bend a man would elbow his way out. He’d leave the upflowing river of people and step onto a landing as his floor came by. But the escalator was still crowded as it passed the one hundred and forty-eighth floor and Winthrop stepped off. He was not one of the lucky ones who lived high near the roof where it was at least possible to think about the air and the light and the sun.

The Standard Fare is so bad that even a potato is considered a luxury:

“I guess the time has come for us to eat that potato. We’ve been saving it for a month.”
Ann’s eyes wrinkled as she looked down at him. “Oh. I—I gave it to the Brookses. They haven’t had anything in weeks.” The words began to pour out. “We have done so well, really, in the last few weeks that I felt sorry for them. We had those cabbage leaves and three potatoes and even that piece of fish four months ago. I couldn’t help myself. I gave—I gave our potato to them. They were so sick of Standard Fare they were beginning to get depressed, really depressed. I—”

Jeremiah is given the egg by a friend:

“Jeremiah, I want you to have something.” Barlow reached down to the bottom of the box and brought out an object that he held toward Winthrop.
Winthrop looked at it and gasped. “An egg. A real hen’s egg. I recognize it from the pictures.” Winthrop looked up. “But I can’t take it, John. I can’t.”
“I want you to have it, Jeremiah. I want you and Ann and Davy to have it. Now don’t argue. I’ll wrap it up and you take it right home.”
Barlow turned and lifted a small box down from a niche. He lined the box with synthetic cotton and gently nestled the egg in the center. After covering the egg with another layer of cotton, he closed the box and wrapped it and tied it with a broad white ribbon under which he slipped a little card of cooking instructions. Then he handed the box to Winthrop. “Take it home, Jeremiah. I’ll be up to see you sometime soon. Go on now.” And he urged Winthrop off the counter and out the door.


For a story that's not widely collected, this is the fourth time we've identified it here. Those two anthologies must be popular ones.

Oh, I didn't think to look. I'll add the duplicates to my answer.

How does a spiral escalator work?

@Shawn Much like a regular escalator, but spiral shaped.  They exist.

@JohnRennie Thank you, thank you, thank you SO MUCH!!!
